# R shiny: Selecting a specific cell from reactive data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame saved in the reactive expression `dframe`. I'd like to select a specific cell from `dframe`. Usually I would simply do something like `dframe[1,2]`, but since `dframe` is reactive, I tried `dframe()[1,2]` as well as `dframe([1,2])` and both were unsuccessful. Is there a way to provide row and column index number arguments to the reactive expression dframe, or at least assign the value of `dframe` to an un-reactive variable that can accept normal index values?

```
server <- function(input,output) {
    dframe <- reactive({data.frame(input$table)})
}
```

Comment: I presume `input$table` corresponds to a `tableOutput`, which you can't read values from. You need to create a `reactive` first with your data, and then render the table based on that `reactive`.

Comment: thank you @GyD! That solved the problem